# Reducing a matrix with given value constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a matrix $M$ , we have to reduce it ,keeping its eigenvalues same but with the constraint that we have to specifically minimize a given set of elements in the matrix. Something like the *Similarity Transformation* with use of pivots could probably help. Here's an example -

$M=\left[\begin{array}{l}a1&a2&a3&a4\\b1&b2&b3&b4\\c1&c2&c3&c4\\d1&d2&d3&d4\end{array}\right]$

I am said that elements $b2$, $b3$,$c1$ and $d2$(say) need to be reduced to as small values as possible, keeping the eigenvalues of the reduced matrix same as initial. What could be a good solution point for this?

Comment: Only square matrices $M\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ have eigenvalues. Your matrix is nor square.

Comment: Sorry about that. Rectified.